# Array not sealing together

Tags: modifiers

So I have a simple wall built and when I go to add an array mod to it, it doesn't seal the two instances together. There's a little crack in between them. Why is this happening?[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the merge threshold in the array modifier ?

Answer (score 0):

Use relative offset - 1 settings in array mod.
Or maybe your mesh vertices that must connected does not co-planar with this object boundary.